# Hangouts notifications not appearing until I open the app

Tags: google-hangouts

My notifications for Google Hangouts are not showing until I open the app. How can I fix this?

Comment: What is your phone model and Android version? If it's Android 6.0+, probably it is caused by [Doze](http://www.androidcentral.com/inside-marshmallow-what-doze-how-do-i-use-it-and-what-does-it-do)

Comment: I have a Nexus 5X and I'm on 7.0.